# I m unable tostore the screenshot into sd card in android

Tags: android, screenshot

I m facing problem with saving the screenshot into sd card in android.

Below is the Code :

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
   switch (view.getId()){

   case R.id.button1:
   tf1 = et2.getText().toString();
   et3.setText(tf1);
   tf2 = et1.getText().toString();
   et4.setText(tf2);
   break;
    case R.id.button2 :
        final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.rl);
        layout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap pic = takeScreenShot(layout);
                try{
                  if(pic != null)
                  {
                      saveScreenShot(pic);
                      Toast.makeText(ik1.this, "Image saved Successfully!",
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(ik1.this, "Unable to save image!",
                              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {}

            }
        });
    {

    }

}

}
    private Bitmap takeScreenShot(View v)
    {
    Bitmap ScreenShot = null;
    try{
    //get width and height
    int width = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    ScreenShot = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //draw canvas
    Canvas c = new Canvas(ScreenShot);
    v.draw(c);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
     {}

    return ScreenShot;
    }
    //Save to external storage
    private void saveScreenShot(Bitmap bm)
    {
    Toast.makeText(ik1.this, "Trying to save image!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = null;
    File file=null;
    try{
        //compress and write to outputstream
        bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50,bao);
        //write as a file to sd card
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
        File.separator + "player.png");
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(bao.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(ik1.this, "Image saved Successfully!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       catch (Exception e)
       {}

      }
```

There is a runtime error in this code as the code is running sucessfully but the image is noot being stored in the sd card. 
The Toast is getting displayed "Image saved sucessfully".
please help.
  I have added the below code ;
Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android permission in Manifest:

Answer (score 0):

Add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android permission in your Manifest:

Then

```
Bitmap bitMapImg;
void saveImage() {
    File filename;
    try {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        new File(path + "/folder/subfolder").mkdirs();
        filename = new File(path + "/folder/subfolder/image.jpg");

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);

        bitMapImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), filename.getAbsolutePath(), filename.getName(), filename.getName());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + filename, 1000).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: would it store the image in gallery if there is no SD Card?

Comment: check this : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29

Comment: What exception you are getting ?